# Prevent flex items from rendering side to side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to center some items in a block, but I want each item inside to be in its own row. For example, I want the orange square to be above the text, but after using flex it's moved it to the side of the text - does anyone know a way around this please?

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="square"></div>

    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this style:

```
.inner {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

That tells the flexbox to display its children in rows instead of columns.  (I know, weird, right?)

**Updated Snippet:**

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="square"></div>

    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`. This means that whenever you give an element `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`, all  *children* of that element will, by default, line up horizontally.*

You can override this default with `flex-direction: column`:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR, you can stay in `flex-direction: row` by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container and giving the children a large enough width (e.g. `width: 100%`) to force only one item per row.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;             /* NEW */
  align-content: center;       /* NEW */
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
}

/* NEW */
p {
  flex: 0 0 100%;            
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>* Note the term "children". Descendants beyond the children do not participate in flex layout.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I see this question coming from this: [Vertically aligning two flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613740/vertically-aligning-two-flex-items)
Which has been marked as duplicate but actually it isn't.

BTW to give a different vertical position of 2 elements set these properties:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

With only 2 elements inside the container, it will show the first on the top and the second on the bottom.
So in order to have 1 of them vertically centred it needs to add a pseudo-element empty to the container, in this way there are 3 elements inside the container.

```
.container:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* Flex properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
}

.item-one {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.item-two {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-one">Item One</div>
  <div class="item-two">Item Two</div>
</div>
```