# Stacking flex items on top of each other

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to build a layout like this one with flexbox:

[image]

how can I stack the items on top of one another?

I build what's on the above screenshot using CSS grid, but failing to do this with flexbox.

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem repeat(2, auto) 2rem;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 4rem auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.layer1 {
  background-color: rgb(64, 213, 187);
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NOTE: This question asks about stacking flex items along the **z-axis**. If you came here looking for "Stacking flex items on top of each other" along the **y-axis**, see this post instead: [prevent flex items from rendering side to side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42723596/3597276).*

---

Flexbox is designed to align elements along columns or rows. It is not designed for stacking.

CSS Grid, however, is perfect for this sort of thing.

A CSS alternative to Grid would be absolute positioning:

(Note that when a [flex item is absolutely positioned](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items), it no longer accepts most flex properties.)

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: salmon;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 250px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: thistle;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tej5g5s1/)

Comment: Pretty much all of them, except for the `order` property: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items